# Use of Global variables

Tags: java, variables

Why is it that when I read others code I frequently see extensive use of "Global variables"?

For instance in Java code:

```
public class SomeClass {
   Button btn1;
   private void someMethod() {
       btn = new Button();
   }
}
```

`btn1` is declared as "global" and a "convenient" variable to be used as easy access throughout the class. But when there is no modifier on it, it defaults to default access in Java.

Could this be a security risk? Why don't people declare them with private modifier right away if they are only planning to use them in only one specific class?

Comment: I don't know who these "people" are, I always declare my fields private, unless I have a very good reason not to.

Comment: I think it is hard to answer why some people do it, we do not know their level ;) in general you are right, it can lead to bugs

Comment: Please use a title that is a question (that can be answered), e.g. "For what reason should i use the default access modifier instead of private?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. btn1 is not a global variable. it is an instance variable of the class
2. if no access modifier is specified, then it defaults to "package" level access i.e. btn1 is accessible to all the classes which belong to the same package as SomeClass
3. if SomeClass is just a data holder and immutable (no setters etc) then this is perfectly OK.
4. It is always better to be as much more restrictive as possible when it comes to the instance variables.

Comment: I completely disagree with 4. I think it's always best to be as restrictive as possible with variables: generally make them private, and if you *can* make them `final` then do so.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - My bad i meant to say more there...English not the 1st language ;-)

Comment: "If SomeClass is just a data holder" and `btn1` is _intended_ to be immutable, then it should be declared `final`. As the code is now, classes in the same package can modify a `SomeClass`'s `btn1`.

Answer (score 5):

It is no global variable (does such a thing even exist in Java? I guess it depends on one's definition of *global*). It is still a class member.

[The default visibility is *package-private*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), so the variable is not public but can be accessed by other classes in the same package.

Normally one should strive for the "best" data encapsulation but there might be uses cases where this is appropriate.

Comment: The closest thing to a global variable in Java would probably be a `public static` variable that's not `final`.

Comment: What does `final` has to do with it? `public static` is global even if the reference is immutable.

Comment: @Steve: if it were `final`, then I wouldn't call it a "variable", but rather a constant (yes, the type might be mutable ...).

Comment: In Java final variables are still referred to as variables.

Comment: SteveKuo Sure, but @JoachimSauer was talking about the "closest thing to a global variable" in Java.  Since Java doesn't have "global variables", there's no reason to assume that what Java calls a "variable" (e.g., a final variable) must qualify as what something else calls a "global variable".

Answer (score 3):

That's not a global variable. It has the default access, so it's not globally visible, and it's an instance member, which means it's scoped to an instance of `SomeClass`. The nearest equivalent to a global variable in Java is a public static field in a public class. Even in that case it's only global with respect to the classloader for the container class you're using - a different classloader running in the same JVM and loading the same container class would have a separate static variable.

Having said all of this, I personally disapprove of fields being anything other than private, to aid encapsulation. (That doesn't give you encapsulation on its own, of course, but it's a start.) Fields are part of the *implementation* of the class, which should be modifiable without affecting anyone only relying on the *API* of the class.

Answer (score 1):

private/public does not have anything to do with security, it is to limit the scope/usage withing your code.

Nevertheless it would be good practice to call them as they should be: so if they should be private, make them private.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "global" in java. There is only public, private, protected and default. Default is generally frowned upon for class variables as it breaks encapsulation.

> Why don't people declare them with private modifier right away if they are only planning to use them in only one specific class?

*Because they are ignorant/don't care/naughty/out to annoy you+

*delete as appropriate
+conspiricy theorists only

Answer (score 1):

If your question is

> Why don't people declare them with private modifier right away

then my answer would be: Because they are lazy.